# how to make deoplete show autocomplete candidates as I type

Tags: vim

Now I get the list of candidates only after I hit `<tab>` (with 'supertab' installed).

Can I configure so that candidate list pops up automatically as I type? (this is the behavior with YouCompleteMe).

Thanks!

Comment: tried it. did not work. is 'supertab' getting in the way?

Comment: are you sure deoplete is working for you? Isn't that `omnicomplet` after you hit tab? Can you see square brackets `[...]` after complete items in the popup menu?

Comment: I have the minimal plugin setup: Vundle, deoplete.nvim, deplete-jedi, supertab.   And python 'neovim'. And the 'g:...startup = 1'. Then autocomplete suggestions show up after I hit <tab>. Add 'g:...start_length = 1' has no effect.

The behavior I want: suggestions show up once available, w/o hitting <tab>

Comment: I do not see [...]. You mean at the bottom of the candidates window? no.

Comment: I guess you're right. I'm not getting more than omnicomplete + supertab. Please help get deoplete to work. Thanks!

Comment: I ment brackets like on deoplete screenshots https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim. You may try to run `:UpdateRemotePlugins` and then `:CheckHealth`

Comment: No I don't have those brackets. So I believe deoplete is not working. I'm using vim not neovim. 'UpdateRemotePlugins' says 'E492: Not an editor command'. Now it seems my vim lacks python3, that might solve things. Fighting... To be realistic, 'neovim' doesn't seem active and big enough for people to switch. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Now my vim supports python3. Still no luck. Is neovim a hard req?

Comment: it is working only with neovim as it is using MessagePack-RPC API. You can read more about it in `:h deoplete`. Neovim is hard requirment for deoplete to work.

Comment: Works now. Thanks. I was mistaken---neovim does seem pretty active and worthwhile.

Comment: I'm using neovim everyday for almost anything related to typing. It's very good, very active. Not sure where you get the opposit idea :)